# Hive version compatibility with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

After various failed tries to use my Hive (1.2.1) with my Spark (Spark 1.4.1 built for Hadoop 2.2.0) I decided to try to build again Spark with Hive.
I would like to know what is the latest Hive version that can be used to build Spark at this point.

When downloading Spark 1.5 source and trying:

```
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.6 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 -Phive -Phive-1.2.1 -Phive-thriftserver  -DskipTests clean package
```

I get :

```
The requested profile "hive-1.2.1" could not be activated because it does not exist.
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Check your spark 1.5 pom.xml it contains hive 1.2.1 version therefore I don't thing you need to specify the hive version explicitly. Simply use mvn without hive version and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to go through this compatibility chart : 
http://hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/asparagus-chart-hdp24.png

Answer (score 0):

Spark website maintains good docs by version number regarding building with Hive support.

e.g. for v1.5 https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/building-spark.html

Listed example shows 2.4 but as the other answer pointed out above you can leave off the `Phive-1.2.1` but according to the docs, if you do that with Spark 1.5.0 it will Build with Hive 0.13 Bindings by default.

```
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -DskipTests clean package
```

Index of all versions: https://spark.apache.org/docs/

Latest version: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html

It appears that it defaults to Hive 1.2.1 bindings from Spark version 1.6.2 onwards. Default doesn't necessarily indicate support limitation though,